# Incremental import using sqoop when column are not incremental

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, sqoop

If I have a table with following fields
`SSN | First Name | Last Name | City | ZipCode`
The primary key is `SSN` and there is no other surrogate primary key for this table.

**On Day 1** - The table got 100 inserts and sqoop is being used to import incremental data from RDBMS to HDFS with `--check-column SSN`
**On Day 2** - The table got another 90 records inserted and about 30 existing records were modified.

Now how can sqoop perform an incremental update as the `--check-column` `"SSN"` though is a good primary key, it is not incremental.
1) So how can sqoop perform an incremental update on this table.
2) And how about the records that were modified on day 2. How can sqoop know about modified records in the above case.

Comment: You need to use --incremental lastmodified for this. Check stack [docs](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sqoop/5673/merge-data-sets-imported-via-incremental-import-using-sqoop/20122/import-new-as-well-as-updated-data-lastmodified-mode#t=201707270646352005932) for details

Comment: i don't think the doc you refereed to can help, the example there points to using `--check-column last_update_date` . In my case I am not the owner of the schema, so I can not modify the source table/schema.  Given these facts, further answers or comments are welcome.

Comment: You need to have timestamp or date column for `lastmodified` incremental mode. Check sqoop [documentation](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_incremental_imports) for details.

Comment: Sqoop will use that imestamp or date column and fetch records newer than that column value. It will fetch both newly inserted and updated data. You don't have that type of column and you can't modify data, so its not possible.

Comment: that answers, so the source schema should support incremental updates. And for the above schema, I don't think even appends are possible as the primary key or `--check-column`  `SSN` field is unique but not incremental.

Comment: exactly........

Comment: we could use pig script to achieve it . data from previous day is in hdfs and after updates or new inserts new data is imported in hdfs using sqoop now we can load both data into pig and join them on the basis of SSN and generate those records where Table b that is updated table SSN is not null this way i get all the updated records/inserted records.
then this file could be used to create hive table where you could either overwrite or create new entries as per scd type you want to follow.
Let me know if i am too vague.

Comment: For the record, some commercial products (Oracle GoldenGate for instance) are capable to "sniff" the database redo logs to reverse-engineer all committed transactions, translate these into a stream of events, and push these to Kafka (or straight to HDFS). That would cost you a leg, but then you could build a list of IDs that have to be refreshed. About the topic of Change Data Capture in general: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_data_capture